# Status of a filtered pull replication with Couchbase Lite

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, database-replication

How do you reliably check that a filtered pull replication has completed successfully with Couchbase Lite?

- The replication status is set to STOPPED on completion or on a fatal error.
- A change listener only fires on incoming changes so can't be used to monitor connection status.
- You can find the seq number of the database but not the last seq of a group of filtered changes.

Comment: Filtered replication from Couchbase Lite now only works with Sync Gateway, not CouchDB / Cloudant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replication object also as a lastError property.  The guide says that if it is set to nil, then there has not been an error since the replication started.  I would check that when you see the replication status go to stopped.

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-ios/#working-with-replications

Comment: Here's the URL for the updated documentation: http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#observing